# How can I set maxIdleTimeMS by command line or mongo-shell?

Tags: mongodb

So, I have deployed my PHP application (using Laravel). However , I've noticed a high connection number in connection pool.

I would like to know how could I to set the [maxIdleTimeMS](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/#urioption.maxIdleTimeMS) parameter through MongoDB Shell or command line (or even via configuration file)?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

> Please, see the important note on below [comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/133231/how-can-i-set-maxidletimems-by-command-line-or-mongo-shell#comment279319_133231) from @jmikola

Comment: On a tangential note, neither the old (`ext-mongo`) nor new (`ext-mongodb`) PHP driver uses a connection pool, so the `maxIdleTimeMS` option is ignored. libmongoc, which is used by the new driver and happens to support connection pools for multi-threaded applications (PHP does not use that mode) also does not support the `maxIdleTimeMS` option at all (see: [CDRIVER-278](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CDRIVER-278)).

Comment: @jmikola Thank you so much for this useful notes. I didn't know that. As you are the main maintainer of PHP Mongodb Client that info  it's so helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maxIdleTimeMS is applicable to MongoDB drivers and is managed on client side. It has nothing to do with MongoDB server so can't be set inside shell